# Select added lines from file

Tags: shell, search, utilities

I have two versions of a file where the newer one has some lines added. The files are sorted (think of wordlists) and I want to print out the newly added lines (given file1 and file2).

I know how to write a little python or perl script to achieve this task, but can it be done with basic UNIX shell utilities, too?

Comment: Add you sample input and desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at `comm(1)`.

what you are looking for is

```
comm -13 file1 file2
```

or

```
comm -3 file1 file2
```

Answer (score 4):

Let a.txt be:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Let `b.txt` be:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
```

Using `comm` with `-3` you can get the desired result:

```
comm -3 a.txt b.txt
ddd
eee
```